# how to get all records with multple joins in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have 4 tables in MYSQL and i want to show count of learner_history table's status column district wise for all 36 districts, however when i query it shows only 1 district result even i tried left join to show district names weather there is data available or not it must show null or zero in its position.Data should be like this for all districts:

[image: data should be like this for all districts]

database structure is like this
[enter image description here][i draw the relation of tables in this image]
please suggest what query would give results like this, thanks.

[i draw the relation of tables in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxN4c.jpg)13.jpg

Comment: Most people where want formatted text instead of images.

Comment: No pictures thanks. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: can someone please suggest solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was pretty awkward to work from with images, but it should get you what you are asking for. Also wasn't sure what you were wanting with 'Str.#' - the example image you gave with 22 as every result wasn't the most helpful.

```
select
District.District_Name as District,
sum(Learner_History.`Status` = 'catchment') as Catchment,
sum(Learner_History.`Status` = 'fresher') as Fresher,
sum(Learner_History.`Status` = 'dropout') as Dropout,
sum(Learner_History.`Status` = 'missout') as Missout,
sum(Learner_History.`Status` = 'mainstrain') as Mainstrain,
sum(Learner_History.`Status` = 'pec') as PEC
from District
left join School on School.District_ID = District.District_ID
left join Learner on Learner.School_ID = School.School_ID
left join Learner_History on Learner_History.Learner_ID = Learner.Learner_ID
group by District.District_Name;
```

Comment: sorry for the bad format. I didn't know at that time how to use StackOverflow. and I have now checked my account after a long time. though I had checked your answer at that time and it did solve my problem at that time. thank you.